# jQuery focus not working form document but working from console

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that adds keyboard accessibility to a drop-down.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".selectButton").focus(function() { 
       alert("Working");
       var href=this.href;
       var opt=href.substr(23,1);
       var torf=href.substring(25);
       showOptions(opt,false);                                          
       $(".optionsDivVisible a:first").focus();
   }).blur(function() {
       $(this).parents("li").removeClass("hover");
   });
});
```

This is working from console and the drop down is showing as soon as the element get focus. But when I add it to the HTML file, it is showing nothing.

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? Is the focus callback not called or does calling `$(".optionsDivVisible a:first").focus()` not have any effect? It is easier for us to help you if you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: The focus callback is not called.It is not even showing the alert. But works perfectly in console.Actually I can't reproduce it as this is using another libraried for converting normal select box into a ul li list.

Comment: Well, it seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/ha3YP/. So without more information (e.g. the actual DOM structure) I don't know if we can provide any more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using another library to load this list from a select box, maybe the dom has the instance of the select box tag instead of the list. That's why you can run your code after the script has ran, in the console.

Try something like `$(".selectButton").live('focus', function() { ...`

Cheers!

Comment: Now one more doubt. After selecting one element from drop-down (selectbox), how focus can be shifted to next element in the form..?

Comment: You didn't supply enough of your code to figure that one out. Sorry. If you can't figure it out yourself, you can open another ticket on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can possibly be in order of the focus given. Try add

```
return false;
```

after the last string of focus handler function.